# Horizontall scrolling in gridview in android

Tags: android, gridview, horizontalscrollview

I'm New in Android application developer and on the stackoverflow.
I've searched a lot on horizontally scrolling in gridview.
I want to show images in grid view as horizontall scrolling.

Please help me.

Comment: You didn't mention what you have tried?

Comment: check http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/01/06/android/android-image-gallery/

Answer (score 0):

hey please check this links it's maybe helpful to you.

1) http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/07/implement-gallery-like.html

2) [Horizontal ListView like Google Catalogs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420339/horizontal-listview-like-google-catalogs)

3) [Android GridView draw dividers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7132030/android-gridview-draw-dividers)

Answer (score 0):

try this in xml file:

```
<HorizontalScrollView 
android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<GridView 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"           
android:id="@+id/gridview" 
android:scrollbars="horizontal"/>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: Have you tried this before you post it as an answer? I guess not.